# This class does not define a public default constructor, or the constructor raised an exception. Internal Exception: java.lang.InstantiationException

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Hi everyone I have problems with my JPA project.
Fichier.java end Application.java implements an interface "FileSystemElement.java"
 Those are my classes 
Application.java

```
package com.bfi.webtop.model;



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/** @pdOid d477195f-149e-4336-8586-19d6a09ee2d4 */
@Entity
@Table(name="application_")
public abstract class Application implements FileSystemElement, Serializable {
//  public Application() {
//      super();
//  }



  public Application(int id_app, String url) {
super();
this.id_app = id_app;
this.url = url;
  }



      public Application() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }



  private int id_app;

  private java.lang.String url;

  /**
  * @return the url
  */
  public java.lang.String getUrl() {
return url;
   }

         /**
  * @param url the url to set
     */
      public void setUrl(java.lang.String url) {
          this.url = url;
    }

    /**
      * @return the id_app
   */
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId_app() {
return id_app;
}

/**
 * @param id_app the id_app to set
 */
public void setId_app(int id_app) {
this.id_app = id_app;
}

}
```

Fichier.java

```
package com.bfi.webtop.model;

/***********************************************************************
 * Module:  Fichier.java
 * Author:  Marwa
 * Purpose: Defines the Class Fichier
 ***********************************************************************/

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public abstract class Fichier implements FileSystemElement {
 private int id_fichier;

   private java.lang.String extension;
   private java.lang.Boolean supprim;
/**
 * @return the extension
 */
public java.lang.String getExtension() {
return extension;
}
/**
 * @param extension the extension to set
 */
 public void setExtension(java.lang.String extension) {
this.extension = extension;
}
/**
 * @return the supprim
 */
public java.lang.Boolean getSupprim() {
return supprim;
}
/**
 * @param supprim the supprim to set
 */
public void setSupprim(java.lang.Boolean supprim) {
this.supprim = supprim;
}
/**
* @return the id_fichier
*/
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId_fichier() {
return id_fichier;
}
/**
 * @param id_fichier the id_fichier to set
*/
 public void setId_fichier(int id_fichier) {
this.id_fichier = id_fichier;
}

public Fichier() {
super();
}

}
```

FileSystemElement.java

```
package com.bfi.webtop.model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value="Dali", date="2013-01-28T10:33:26.416+0100")
@StaticMetamodel(FileSystemElement.class)
public class FileSystemElement_ {
}
```

The other classes have the same structures
When I try to do: jpa tooles> generate tables from entities I have the following mistakes

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception >[EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [webtop] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
>   Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
>
> ### Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-34] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: This class does not define a public default constructor, or the constructor raised an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.InstantiationException
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.bfi.webtop.model.Application --> [DatabaseTable(application_)])

Exception [EclipseLink-34] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: This class does not define a public default constructor, or the constructor raised an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.InstantiationException
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.bfi.webtop.model.Fichier --> [DatabaseTable(FICHIER)])

Exception [EclipseLink-34] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: This class does not define a public default constructor, or the constructor raised an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.InstantiationException
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.bfi.webtop.model.Raccourci -->  [DatabaseTable(RACCOURCI)])

### Runtime Exceptions:

```
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:616)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:596)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.perform(Main.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services -       2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
```

Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [webtop] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services -  2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException

I am using Eclipse Juno
Any help please?

}

Comment: Why do you have the default no arg Application constructor commented out?  The errors state EclipseLink cannot initiate new instances of your classes so it is likely related.

Comment: Where is the `FileSystemElement` interface? I see only a `FileSystemElement_` class.

Comment: And why are `Application` and `Fichier` classes abstract?

Answer (score 8):

You've defined your class Fichier as abstract:

```
public abstract class Fichier
```

Remove *abstract* and it'll work. The error message in this case is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you need to provide a default (no argument) constructor for you Application class.

The constructor can be private if you do not want to expose it to your app.

Comment: That didn't change anything James

Comment: The constructor should NOT be private, as it breaks with the JPA2 specification, which states: `The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may have other constructors as well.
The no-arg constructor must be public or protected`

Answer (score 0):

Consider create no-arg constructor in your class, then clean you project and try.
I had the same problem and using lombok I fixed it